# iOS app crashes on Code Review question

Tags: bug, ios-app

Maybe because of the very long code snippet?

[ASCII text-based RPG game in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172170/ascii-text-based-rpg-game-in-c)

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)